# Conversational Space Filler (Translation of "um...")

Tags: переклад

Some languages have different versions of "uh..." or "um..." For example, Spanish uses "es de..." to fill the same function. Does Ukrainian have its own word?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, we call these *слова-паразити* (parasite words). There are several kinds of these, and the linguists and avid language speakers often consider these words harmful, however, each category to a greater or lesser extent.

- **Filler words** are used when a speaker makes a pause to think what they say next or looking for a good wording. They usually have [onomatopoeic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia) nature, so they are mostly similar to their English counterparts.
  Examples are *гм, хм, м-м-м, е-е-е*, etc.
  They are often considered less harmful, and many speakers do not protest against it;
- Words that appear due to **inability of the speaker to fill the pause**.
  These words are *ну* or *ну-у-у* (well), *значить* ({this} means), *так би мовити* (so to say), *чесно кажучи* (frankly speaking), *коротше* (briefly; in short), *ніби* and *типу* (kind of), *до речі* (by the way), *це са́ме* (this very), *насправді* (in reality; indeed), *взагалі{-то}* (in general);
- **Emotional parasites** often appear as a part of youth slang: *реально* (really), *капець* (disappointment or failure, derived from *кінець* = "the end" and the German word *kaputt* = "ruined"), *тупо* (dumbly), *просто* (simply), *прямо* (straight);
- **Feedback parasites**: *тю* (a contraction of *тьху*, phew/shoo), *так?* (isn't it?), *справді?* (really?), *та ну?* (come on; tell me; get out!), *самі розумієте* (you know).

A classical example in Ukrainian literature is the person of Voznyy in Ivan Kotlyarevsky's stage play [**"Natalka Poltavka"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natalka_Poltavka) (1819) (Возний у пʼєсі І. Котляревського «Наталка Полтавка»). His speech was full of parasite words, weird mixture of Russian and Ukrainian words, and [канцелярит](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Officialese), a bureaucratic speech of Russian officials who were otherwise unable to formulate their thoughts. Here's how Voznyy expressed his love to Natalka:

> *Бачив я многих — і ліпообразних, і багатих, но серце моє не імієть, **теє-то як його**, к ним поползновенія. Ти одна заложила ему позов на вічнії роки, і душа моя ежечасно волаєть тебе і послі нищпорной даже години.*

When Natalka admits that she does not comprehend his "highly educated speech", he tries to speak in simpler words:

> *Так знай же, що я тебе давно уже, **теє-то як його**, полюбив, як тільки ви перейшли жити в наше село.*